# Recursive crawl through a hierachy of list of various record types

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I have a data structure that is comprises of a list of F# records for which one of the member itself is a list of records of a different type as so on to about 4 levels deep hierarchy. The code I have to create this structure is a little verbose but works. I wish now create a generic tail recursive function that decomposes the lists of this data structure from the top level in the hierarchy to produce a map the count counts of number of items in a list bottom level of the hierarchy. I can develop the required code by create functions to decompose the records at each level of the hierarchy, but you with end up with the same recursion function to handle the lists but of the different record types. The following is how I tried to implement this in a non-verbose way, but I get the follow error:

> This runtime coercion or type test from type
>       `'a`
>    to
>       `MarshallingPanel`
>   involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Runtime type tests are not allowed on some types.

I understand the error is type inference in F# and the Type Test Pattern matching examples I could find either involve a base class reference or a Discriminated Unions. I'm going to try a union and if that does not work do it verbosely, but if any of you F# gurus have the pattern to follow or any input that would be great.

```
let rec mapAsRequired items (currentCBMap: Map<string*string*string*string, int>) =
    match items with
        | head :: tail ->
            match head with
                | :? MarshallingPanel as marshallingPanel ->
                        mapAsRequired marshallingPanel.PLCs currentCBMap
                | :? PLC as plc ->
                        mapAsRequired plc.Racks currentCBMap
                | :? Rack as rack ->
                        mapAsRequired rack.Slots currentCBMap
                | _ ->
                    mapAsRequired [] currentCBMap
            mapAsRequired tail currentCBMap
        | [] ->
            currentCBMap

let rec mapMarshallingPanels (marshallingPanels:MarshallingPanel list) (currentCBMap: Map<string*string*string*string, int>) = 
    match marshallingPanels with
        | head :: tail ->
            mapMarshallingPanels tail (mapAsRequired (List.sortBy(fun (plc:PLC) -> rankProcessorForCBAlllocation plc.PLCNo) head.PLCs) currentCBMap)
        | [] ->
            currentCBMap

mapAsRequired marshallingPanels Map.empty
```

Comment: This definitely looks like a good case for a DU - you should try to avoid the `:? ...` pattern match as it tends to show that you aren't using the type system well

Comment: I currently suspect the my issue with is my implementation of the original data structure. I suspect that I needed to have created the original data structure with DU or recursive type that provided to a single generic list member that I can recursively call. Wrapping the existing Record types into a DU provided a means to perform pattern matching recursivly but but current data structure only return a list of a particular type of record. Through type inference recursive function requires a list of the DU wrapper. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the problem, you need to match on something of type `obj` rather than on a value of a indeterminate type (type parameter `'a`). You can do that by adding `box`:

```
match box head with 
| :? MarshallingPanel as marshallingPanel -> 
    mapAsRequired marshallingPanel.PLCs currentCBMap 
| :? PLC as plc -> 
    mapAsRequired plc.Racks currentCBMap
```

However, I fully agree with John Palmer's comment that using a discriminated union seems like a better choice for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks I had a quick go using box that the match does allow the first case but type inference now requires the recursive call back to itself only accept a list of the record type in the first match. I will try using a DU.

Comment: @JoseGarces I think you could get it to work by adding a type annotation `mapAsRequired (items:list<#obj>) ...`, but I'd definitely try using DUs first.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. I tried simply creating a DU of the different record types and attempt to recursive through the list of DU types. But I was not able to call the recursive function with the parent member list of child record types since it required a list of DU types. You may have a way of doing this but I suspect to should have utilised a DU or recursive type in the original data structure. I resorted to repeating the recursive function for each level of the hierachy. But thanks for your help. Maybe if I read your book a solution will present itself. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @JoseGarces It's a bit hard to answer without seeing the type declarations. Your recursive calls would have to run on the values of the same DU type though...